# GeoServer: is grades to degrees transformation possible through SLD file?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I work on GeoServer 2.6.2 and PosgreSQL 9.2 / PostGIS 2.0. I have declared a layer in GeoServer which is linked to a PostgreSQL database table. In this table, I have a column (`obj_orientation`) storing orientation values in grades (360° = 400 gr.). Is it possible to transform these values to degrees inside to SLD stylesheet?

I have tried these but the layer doesn't display at all:

```
<Rotation>
   <ogc:PropertyName>obj_orientation*0.9</ogc:PropertyName>
</Rotation>

<Rotation>${obj_orientation*0.9}</Rotation>

<Rotation>${obj_orientation}*0.9</Rotation>
```

Is there a way to do so or do I have to update my column in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the mul function (see [Filter Expressions](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html#filter-expressions)). So something like:

```
<rotation>
   <mul>
      <literal>${obj_orientation}</literal>
      <literal>0.9</literal>
   </mul>
</rotation>
```